# Products of functions is Hölder continous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I have $A$ maps $\Omega$ into the $n\times n$ real matrices, where $\Omega$ is a open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$. $C^{\alpha}(\Omega)$ denotes the set of functions that are Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha\in(0,1]$ on each $K$ compact subset of $\Omega$. I want to show that $A(x)^{T}A(x)\in C^{\alpha}(\Omega)$. $\|A\|$ denotes the induced norm of the matrix $A$. I tried to do so: 
$x,y\in K$ 
\begin{align}
|A(x)^{T}A(x)- A(y)^{T}A(y)|& =|(A(x)^{T}-A(y)^{T})A(x)+A(y)^{T}(A(x)-A(y))|\\
& \leq |A(x)^{T}-A(y)^{T}| |A(x)| + |A(y)^{T}| |A(x)-A(y)| \\ & \leq 
C|x-y|^{\alpha} \|A\||x|+C|x-y|^{\alpha} \|A\| |y|= C'|x-y|^{\alpha}
\end{align}

With $C'=C \|A\|(|x|+|y|)$. Is that right? Thank you.

Comment: If you understood that $\|A\|$ is the norm of $A|_K$, then it looks okay to me.